# Pass Python variable inside command with Paramiko

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssh, paramiko

With this command, I want to save an output of the `smartctl` command of the sda drive.

Now, since I use RAID, I have multiple drives, not just sda.

The following command works fine:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('/bin/su root -c "smartctl -a /dev/sda > /tmp/smartctl_output1"', get_pty=True) # ORIGINAL
```

I want to achieve that I pass local Python variable "DISK" containing sda, sdb, sdc and so on instead only static value.

The following line produces error:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('/bin/su root -c "smartctl -a /dev/" + DISK + " > /tmp/" + DISK', get_pty=True)
```

**edit:** tried this as well:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('/bin/su root -c "smartctl -a /dev/' + DISK + ' > /tmp/' + DISK, get_pty=True)
stdin.write(ROOTPASS)
stdin.write('\n')
DEBUG1=stdout.read()
print   "DEBUG COMMAND= " + DEBUG1
```

Produces the following error and file in /tmp/ + DISK not created:

> DEBUG COMMAND= bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
>   bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: Is `DISK` a local Python variable or an environment variable on the server?

Comment: `DISK` is local variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has nothing to do with Paramiko.

It's just a trivial concatenation of strings in Python:

```
ssh.exec_command(
     '/bin/su root -c "smartctl -a /dev/' + DISK + ' > /tmp/' + DISK + '"',
     get_pty=True)
```

For even better options, see [How to insert string into a string as a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52155591/850848)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, tried dozens of quotations combinations including yours as well, looks like it does not work. I have updated the question.

Comment: ah, after your edit it works just like I wanted, thanks alot @martin-prikryl