# How to insert string into a string as a variable?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, variables

I'm trying to create a program and one thing I'm trying to do is add variables to a string like so.

```
EnemyHealth = 0  

EnemyIs = 'dead'

print("The Enemy's health is %d. The Enemy is %d." % (EnemyHealth,EnemyIs)
```

But everytime I try that it won't let me use a string as one of the variables. How would I insert a variable string into another string?

P.S. I am using python 3.7.0

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are 4 approaches I am aware of for achieving this on python (Python 3):

**1) Concatenation:**

You can do this using `+` for joining 2 strings, however you can only concatenate string type data, meaning non string type data needs to be converted to string using the `str()` function. For example:

```
print("The Enemy's health is " + str(EnemyHealth) + ". The Enemy is " + EnemyIs + ".") 
# output = "The Enemy's health is 0. The Enemy is dead."
```

**2) Taking advantage of Python 3's `print()` function which can take multiple parameter arguments:**

Here your `print()` statement similar to the concatenation statement above, except where ever I use `+` to concatenate you need to replace it with `,`. The advantage of using this, is that different data types will be automatically converted to string, i.e. no longer needing the `str()` function. For example:

```
print("The Enemy's health is ", EnemyHealth, ". The Enemy is ", EnemyIs, ".") 
# output = "The Enemy's health is 0. The Enemy is dead."
```

**3) Using your string replacement approach**

The reason your code doesnt work, is because `%d` means you will replace it with an integer and therefore to make your code work, for the string stored on the variable `EnemyIs` needs to be replaced with `%s` which is used to state that it will be replaced with a string. Therefore to solve your problem you need to do:

```
print("The Enemy's health is %d. The Enemy is %s." % (EnemyHealth, EnemyIs)) 
# output = "The Enemy's health is 0. The Enemy is dead."
```

**4) The `format()` method for python strings (This is the best approach to use)**

This is a built in method for all strings in python, which allow you to easily replace the placehoder `{}` within python strings, with any variables. Unlike solution number 3 above, this `format()` method doesnt require you to express or convert different data types to string, as it would automatically do this for you. For example, to make your print statement work you can do:

```
print("The Enemy's health is {}. The Enemy is {}.".format(EnemyHealth, EnemyIs))
```

OR

```
print("The Enemy's health is {0}. The Enemy is {1}.".format(EnemyHealth, EnemyIs)) 

# output = "The Enemy's health is 0. The Enemy is dead."
```

### UPDATE:

**5) [F-Strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)**

As of python 3.6+, you can now also use f-strings, to substitute variables within a string. This method is similar to the the `.format()` method described above, and in my oppinion is a better upgrade to the `str.format()` method. To use this method all you have to do is state `f` before your opening quote when defining a string and then, within the string use the format, `{[variable name goes here]}` for this to work. For example, to make your print statement work, using this method, you can do:

```
print(f"The Enemy's health is {EnemyHealth}. The Enemy is {EnemyIs}.")
# output = "The Enemy's health is 0. The Enemy is dead."
```

As you can see by using this method, the `variable name` is being instanciated directly within the curly brackets `{}`.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realise that %d and %s were different.

Comment: @PLP123 No problem, but yes, do make use of the `str.format()` method instead, because it not only makes it cleaner, but also saves you the hassle of having to convert different data types into string.

Answer (score 4):

Avoid % format specifiers in Python3.x

From the Docs :

> old style of formatting will eventually be removed from the language, str.format() should generally be used.

There are few simple ways to do this, check below code :

```
print("The Enemy's health is {} The Enemy is {}".format(EnemyHealth, EnemyIs)

print("The Enemy's health is {0} The Enemy is {1}".format(EnemyHealth, EnemyIs)

print("The Enemy's health is {EnemyHealth} The Enemy is {EnemyIs}".format(EnemyHealth=EnemyHealth, EnemyIs=EnemyIs)
```

Comment: This answer would be better if you explained  _why_ someone should avoid % substitutions in python 3.x.

Comment: @BryanOakley Update added

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code is that you are using `%d` for the second argument. The `%d` is intended for integers, while `%s` is intended for strings. You can make it work by changing to `%s` like this:

```
EnemyHealth = 0
EnemyIs = 'dead'
print("The Enemy's health is %d. The Enemy is %s." % (EnemyHealth, EnemyIs))
```

**Output**

```
The Enemy's health is 0. The Enemy is dead.
```

An alternative is to use the format function like this:

```
print("The Enemy's health is {}. The Enemy is {}.".format(EnemyHealth, EnemyIs))
```

More on string formatting can be found [here](https://pyformat.info).

Answer (score 2):

Use print with `format`, it makes your code look good

```py
print("The Enemy's health is {} The Enemy is {}".format(str(EnemyHealth),EnemyIs)
```

Answer (score 2):

The format specifier for a string object is `%s`. So your code should be:

```
EnemyHealth = 0   
EnemyIs = 'dead'
print("The Enemy's health is %d. The Enemy is %s." % (EnemyHealth,EnemyIs))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `print("The Enemy's health is %d.  The Enemy is %s." % (EnemyHelath, EnemyIs))`, though `print("The Enemy's health is {}.  The Enemy is {}.".format(EnemyHealth,EnemyIs))` is recommended.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `%d` in your first string expects an integer variable in its place. What you want is `%s` for strings.

That is:

```
print("The Enemy's health is %d. The Enemy is %s." % (EnemyHealth,EnemyIs)
```

(Also have in mind that `%f` is for floats and you can use some tricks like `%2.4f` will write number 1.234567 as 01.2346)

Comment: I didn't realise they were for different uses. Thanks.