# How to put the contents of a (string) variable inside a string using a function - Python

Tags: python, string

My goal is to execute something along the lines of `print("\"text\"")`, while keeping `var` as a changeable variable.

code:

```
var = "text"

print(str(var))
```

expected output: `"text"`

actual output: `text`

Answer (score 1):

You could use [repr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr)

```py
print(repr(var))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use f-string ?

```
var = "textlol"

print(f"\"{var}\"")
```

Comment: You wouldn't need to escape the double quotes inside an f-string of single quotes. ```print(f'"{var}"')``` would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy as you see in below:

```
var = '"text"'
print(var)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to insert your string value into the string that is printed. There are a few ways to do this, take a look at [this answer on a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52155770/15469537).

In your case, you want to print `"` around the string. As `"` is a special character, you'll need to insert a backslash before it to 'escape' it, and print the `"` instead of ending the string. The end result would be something like

```
var = "text"
print("\"{}\"".format(var))
```

Comment: The solution offered by AKiani offers the same functionality, but you don't need to escape the `"` as it uses single quotes `'` for the outer string, and double quotes `"` for the string that is printed

Comment: The solution by Henry Ecker is even cleaner. If it works for you that's what I'd recommend.

Comment: @HenryEcker I understand what you mean, but the question wanted to keep 'var = "text"' as it was, without changing it. I think this answer shows a possible solution, though replacing [[  print("\"{}\""  ]] with [[  print(' "{}" ')  ]] does indeed make it cleaner...

Answer (score 0):

add the quotation marks when you print it. This way you don't have to change the variable.

Example:

```
var = "text"
print('"'+'text'+'"')
```

Output: "text"