# How to send the contents of a variable to Micropython repl

Tags: python, serial-port, micropython

I  am trying to create a file in an ESP32 named "PassWord" containing a password, using Micropython Serial. The code below works with a "hardwired" password, but I would like to be able to send the contents of a variable that was typed in by the user. The sending script is running in Win10 using Python 3.7.9

```
import serial
import time

def Send(s):
    ser.write((s +'\r\n').encode())
    time.sleep(.3)
    z = ser.read(ser.in_waiting)

portx = "COM6"
bps = 115200
timex = 5
ser = serial.Serial(portx,bps,timeout=timex)

Send("f = open('Password,'w')")
Send("f.write('MyPassWord\\n')")
Send("f.close()")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert string into a string as a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52155591/how-to-insert-string-into-a-string-as-a-variable)

Comment: Unfortunately, it does NOT. But thanks anyway...

Comment: what is the specific problem that you are having?

Comment: if I create a variable  MyPassword = "123xyz" and  Send("f.write('MyPassword\\n')") I will get a line written "MyPassword" not the value "f.write('123xyz')"

Comment: You are not writing a variable to the file. Just the String MyPassword

Comment: That is correct. That is the problem. I want to write the contents of the variable to the file.

Comment: Just posted an answer did that work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this. Just made this as an exaggerated example so you can learn. You could put this whole thing into the send function input if you wanted.

```
import serial
import time

MyPassWord = "This is the password"


def Send(s):
    ser.write((s +'\r\n').encode())
    time.sleep(.3)
    z = ser.read(ser.in_waiting)

portx = "COM6"
bps = 115200
timex = 5
ser = serial.Serial(portx,bps,timeout=timex)

StringToSend = """f.write('""" + MyPassWord+ """\\n')"""

Send("f = open('Password,'w')")
Send(StringToSend)
Send("f.close()")
```

Comment: One small problem. If MyPassword contains a (single ie." ' ") quote the routine will not work. But it does handle double quotes.

Comment: Should have explained better. The real purpose of this is is to send a Micropython script to an ESP32 using serial. Although your solution does work perfectly for passwords, over which I have control, and will use.

Comment: You could change MyPassWord = "This is the password" to MyPassWord = """This is the password""" then you should be able to put whatever you want in there.

Comment: That did not work. I am having problems with lines that contain both single and double-quotes.                  I tried:                               
MyPassWord = """f = open('filename', "w")"""           But that did not work, it wrote nothing at all