# I don't understand why this is a "syntax error"?

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

I am trying to make a list of messages that will be randomly chosen from. I keep getting syntax error, I'm trying to figure out what I've missed?

I have looked over the code and can't see anything, but I feel like there's something I don't know about, I tried online checkers, but they just say errror and don't show me what the error is ...

```py
messageRnd = ['Countdown time!'(days_left)'','OMG! '(dayt_left)'days to go!!', 'Just a reminder, there are'(days_left)' days to go!', ' '(days_left)'days left!', 'T-'(days_left)' to takeoff.', 'did you know there are '(days_left) 'days until we takeoff?']
```

Comment: Your quote marks are all over the place. Remember that, in python, inner quotes that you want to print must be a different style than the quote marks that denote a string. Perhaps `'Countdown time!'(days_left)''` should be `'Countdown time!"(days_left)"'`?

Comment: Also, it might be worth taking a look at [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52155591/how-to-insert-string-into-a-string-as-a-variable) if you expect to actually include a `days_left` variable in your strings rather than the string literal `'(days_left)'`

Comment: Also, try to use syntax highlighting in your IDE.

Comment: The very first probably-intended-to-be-an-element-of-a-list is broken, and possibly others as well.  You can't concatenate python strings simply by opening & closing quotes, even `'Countdown time!'days_left` is a syntax error.  See https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_string_concatenation.asp for how you're supposed to do this

Comment: I'm going to post the whole code, because now it's just posting (days_left) instead of the number I want.

Comment: You can use format strings to insert variable when a string is created, but if you want that number to depend on the `days_left` variable at the time the string is picked out, you should could leave it as it is and do something like `message = message.replace("days_left", days_left)`, which would replace the string "days_left" with the value currently stored in the variable called `days_left`.

Answer (score 1):

```
from random import randint 
while True:
    days_left = str(randint(0,100))
    messageRnd = ['Countdown time! ' + (days_left),
              'OMG! ' + (days_left) + ' days to go!!',
              'Just a reminder, there are ' + (days_left) + ' days to go!',
              (days_left) + ' days left!',
              'T-' + (days_left) + ' to takeoff.',
              'Did you know there are ' + (days_left) + ' days until we takeoff?']
    print(messageRnd[randint(0,len(messageRnd) - 1)].replace("days_left", days_left))
```

You cannot just put the variable name in, you need a `,` or `+` to concatenate. Here you need to use `+` as the variable would be treated as a separate entry in the list instead.

You would be far better off using an f string if you want to include many variables in a string as it is easier to type and read.

This allows you to have a more readable list, at the cost of having to redefine it if `days_left` changes:

```
from random import randint    
while True:
        days_left = str(randint(0,100))
        messageRnd = [f'Countdown time! {days_left}',
                    f'OMG! {days_left} days to go!!',
                    f'Just a reminder, there are {days_left} days to go!',
                    f'{days_left} days left!',
                    f'T-{days_left} to takeoff.',
                    f'Did you know there are {days_left} days until we take off?']
        print(messageRnd[randint(0,len(messageRnd) - 1)])
```

As Cmd858 said in the comments, you could also do the following to avoid having to redefine the list while having the readability advantage:

```
from random import randint 
messageRnd = ['Countdown time! days_left',
            'OMG! days_left days to go!!',
            'Just a reminder, there are days_left days to go!',
            'days_left days left!',
            'T-days_left to takeoff.',
            'Did you know there are days_left days until we take off?']
while True:
    days_left = str(randint(0,100))
    print(messageRnd[randint(0,len(messageRnd) - 1)].replace("days_left", days_left))
```

Comment: One thing to note here is that the list would have to be created again if the value of `days_left` changed, which isn't really a problem but might not be ideal.